# ActionBar-PullToRefresh Gradle Error

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar-compat

I'm trying to working with ActionBar-PullToRefresh library Chris Banes but I got to error when I import to him library.

I can't see smooth progress bar lib from github and my build.gradle file looks like wrong. All of the line has error "Cannot resolve symbol ...."

How can I works this library?

And when I rebuild the library, I got this message *"android-apt-compiler: [library] /Users/emreozdemir/Desktop/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/library/res/values/styles.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'SmoothProgressBar'."*

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:0.2.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        // This should be 14, but is 7 because extra-abc/extra-abs depend on this library
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
               java.srcDirs = ['src']
               res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}

apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

But looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you should also import 'SmoothProgressBar' library in your project https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar

Answer (score 0):

you can add pull to refresh without Action bar Library see this link you can do with swipe-view layout

**http://www.incredibleandros.com/swiperefershlayout-android-example/**

Answer (score 0):

I've succesfully imported PullToRefresh into Android Studio 1.0.

Check out my reply in [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007586/pulltorefresh-add-to-gradle/27992358#27992358)

For more info, [This post](https://mobiledevstories.wordpress.com/2015/01/16/android-sdk-importing-pulltorefresh-to-gradle-for-using-in-android-studio/)

Hope it helps! :-)