# Pulltorefresh add to gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, pull-to-refresh

can anyone help me add this library in build.gradle Android Studio.

```
https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh
```

I know it is deprecated but I want to use it, I would appreciate if someone could help me

what to write in

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile '????'
}
```

as mentioned I want to use the deprecated library not new Actionbar-Pulltorefresh. tried to google it but couldn't find any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you to use ActionBarPullToRefresh (same author).

However, if you would like to use PullToRefresh, you have to clone the lib locally in a folder, and then add it as local dependency. This lib isn't on Central Maven as aar.

```
root
  app
    build.gradle
  lib
    pull
      src
      res
      build.gradle
  settings.gradle
```

In you `app/build.gradle` you have to add:

```
dependencies {
    // Library
    compile project(':lib:pull')
}
```

In lib/pull/build.gradle you have to define it as library and specify the right sourceset (it is a gist):

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['aidl']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

In settings.gradle:

```
include ':lib:pull' ,':app'
```

Comment: im on mac and my app's location is /Users/wasif/MyApp so i have to put this library in /Users/wasif/Pulltorefresh right???

Comment: You can choose any folder inside your root project.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to add *ActionBar-PullToRefresh* to your project is via Gradle, you just need to add the following dependency to your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {  
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
}
```

Rest gradle will do all work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've succesfully imported the libproject in Android Studio 1.0. The steps are the following

1.- Download and install PullToRefresh from the official [GitHub](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh). Unzip it. 
2.- Create an empty Android Studio project. Mine is named "PrjLibDeps" 
3.- In project's root folder, create a folder named "libs". Inside libs/, copy a "pulltorefresh" folder containing the unzipped file. Structure remains as shown below:

```
PrjLibdeps
|   settings.gradle
|   build.gradle
|   libs
      |  pulltorefresh
            | src, res, LICENSE, pom.xml...
|  app/
|   build.gradle
|   src
| ...
```

4.- Create a build.gradle file inside "pulltorefresh" folder. Copy-paste this sample code and set proper values to compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion (just copy them from app/build.gradle)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
android {
  compileSdkVersion 20
  buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
  defaultConfig {
     minSdkVersion 9
     targetSdkVersion 20
  }
  sourceSets {
    main {
       manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
       java.srcDirs = ['src']
       res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
  }
}
```

5.- on app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   compile project(":PullToRefresh")
}
```

6.- Now, on project_root/settings.gradle:

```
include ‘:app', ':PullToRefresh'
project (':PullToRefresh').projectDir = new File('libs/pulltorefresh')
```

7.- "Sync now" 
8.- CMD+F9 (Make project)

Hope it helps!
more detailed info [in my blog](https://mobiledevstories.wordpress.com/2015/01/16/android-sdk-importing-pulltorefresh-to-gradle-for-using-in-android-studio/)